# Angular Can not use Scss in new generated component

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

As shown below Error
Error1:

[image]

> [WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented. 
> ./src/app/products/products.component.sass
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

This is my code:

```
\\This is my new components product.components.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.sass']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Here is error

> ERROR in ./src/app/products/products.component.sass
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
> #DIV_1 {
> ^
> Invalid CSS after "#DIV_1 {": expected "}", was "{"
> in ...\src\app\products\products.component.sass (line 1, column 9)
> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Can you share your products.component.sass ?

Comment: I think there is notthing wrokng about the scss because It' error in the first line and even I put only one line or any thing in here. it Error.
#DIV_1 {
    block-size: 10260.9px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are using curly brackets in a .sass file.

If you want to use brackets you need to use .scss extension

Read the difference here: [Sass: Syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax)